Why are the data relations not working in C#?
I have a project with two tables, Loans and LoanTypes, and as shown below I've set them up with model classes. The problem is in my controller: when I list loans, there is no LoansType for this loan.
Loans model class:
namespace ACB.Models
{
    public class Loans
    {
        public ulong? LoansID { get; set; }
        public string? FullName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LoanTypesID")]
        public ulong LoanTypesID { get; set; }  // relation ulong
        public LoanTypes LoanTypes { get; set; } 
    }
}

LoanTypes model class:
namespace ACB.Models
{
    public class LoanTypes 
    {
        public ulong? LoanTypesID { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string Profit { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Loans> Loanss { get; } = new List<Loans>();
    }
}

This is in the controller's action method:
var loan = _context.Loans
                   .Where(x => x.AccountsID == creditorAccountId)
                   .FirstOrDefault();

// Calculate Profit based on loan type
if (loan.LoanTypes.Type == "fixed")
{
    loan.Profit = Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(loan.LoanTypes.Profit));
}
else if (loan.LoanTypes.Type == "countable")
{
    if (Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(loan.LoanTypes.Profit)) > 0 && 
        Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(loan.LoanTypes.Profit)) < 1)
    {
        long max = Convert.ToInt64((loan.LoanAmount * Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(loan.LoanTypes.Profit))) / 12);
        long min = Convert.ToInt64((loan.Capital * Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(loan.LoanTypes.Profit))) / 12);
        loan.Profit = max + min / 2;
    }
}

In the DbContext :
namespace ACB.Data
{
    public class ACBDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ACBDbContext(DbContextOptions<ACBDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Loans> Loans { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LoanTypes> LoanTypes { get; set; }

        public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Loans>()
                        .ToTable("loans");

            modelBuilder.Entity<LoanTypes>()
                        .ToTable("loanTypes")
                        .HasMany(a => a.Loanss)
                        .WithOne(b => b.LoanTypes);
           
            // Consider configuring indexes and relationships for efficient querying

            modelBuilder.Entity<LoanTypes>()
                        .HasMany(b => b.Loanss)
                        .WithOne(p => p.LoanTypes)
                        .HasForeignKey(p => p.LoanTypesID);
        }

        public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync<T>(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) where T : class
        {
            var dbSet = this.Set<T>();
            return await dbSet.FindAsync(new object[] { id }, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}

I'm working with ASP.NET Core 8 MVC and Entity Framework Core 8.

You need to include the LoanTypes in your context. The accepted answer to this post explains it pretty well

this is how i implement it in my db context
public DbSet Loans { get; set; }
public DbSet LoanTypes { get; set; }
    modelBuilder.Entity<Loans>().ToTable("loans");
    modelBuilder.Entity<LoanTypes>().ToTable("loanTypes").HasMany(a => a.Loanss).WithOne(b => b.LoanTypes);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LoanTypes>()
                    .HasMany(b => b.Loanss)
                    .WithOne(p => p.LoanTypes)
                    .HasForeignKey(p => p.LoanTypesID); @ChrisFromTheBlock


Please [edit] your question if you have new information.

Of-topic: rename Loans to Loan. Classes should have singular names. Then property Loanss can be renamed to Loans. (Same for LoanType.) Also, remove the [ForeignKey("LoanTypesID")] attribute, it's wrong and redundant.

Off topic but how does sql server handle these ulongs? will they be mapped to BigInt?

it's convert it in SQL Server to 'BigInt' @topsail

I did change name for models and controllers but nothing change the same error which is no relational database. @GertArnold

That's why I said "off-topic", it wasn't meant as a fix, just a code improvement. As said in the very first comment: try Include.

I Did as Below but nothing change still no relations: var loan = _context.Loan.Include(l => l.LoanType).Where(x => x.AccountsID == creditorAccountId).FirstOrDefault(); @GertArnold

Try to change ulong? into long. Then edit your question and make it contain the current code including the previous recommendations.

I did solve the problem with Eager loading not by Include but by following code:
var paginatedList = await PaginatedList<Loan>.CreateAsync(data.AsNoTracking(), pageIndex, pageSize);
        paginatedList.ForEach(x => 
        {
            x.LoanTypes= _context.LoanTypes.First(y => y.LoanTypesID== x.LoanTypesID);
        });

By this way of intilazing related data it is eager loading way.
Thanks all for your awnsers and comments.

Include should do exactly the same thing. If it doesn't something else is going on.

Include is not working for me why I don't know, But eager loading is working fine when I make like in answer post it's working fine. Thanks. @GertArnold

To include related entities you either need to eager load them using Include, or enable lazy loading. (which can incur significant performance issues)
So in the controller action:
var loan = _context.Loans
    .Include(x => x.LoanTypes)
    .Where(x => x.AccountsID == creditorAccountId)
    .FirstOrDefault();

Which can be simplified to:
var loan = _context.Loans
    .Include(x => x.LoanTypes)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountsID == creditorAccountId);

If using an "OrDefault" you should be asserting that a loan is returned before accessing, for instance:
var loan = _context.Loans
    .Include(x => x.LoanTypes)
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.AccountsID == creditorAccountId);
if (loan == null)
    return NotFound();

If instead you want to handle exceptions if a requested row isn't found use First or Single
var loan = _context.Loans
    .Include(x => x.LoanTypes)
    .First(x => x.AccountsID == creditorAccountId);

This will throw a more meaningful exception on this row in the stack trace than a NullReferenceException on a line that accesses the loan which may include other references with no indication which reference is #null.
Note that Include works on Linq query expressions, not Find() so when fetching aggregate structures use First/Single rather than Find on the DbSet.

I did what you wrote and done nothing still no relations, thanks for your answer. @Steve_Py

Double check that at runtime that your web application is pointing at the same database you are checking against. In the controller action add a debugging line: var connectionString = _context.Database.GetConnectionString(); and a breakpoint to inspect the connection string. It's been a fairly common issue where the runtime web.config (if IIS) or .config used at runtime is left pointing at an unexpected database instance.

Thanks for this tip for debugging. @steve-py

By default, Entity Framework Core does not automatically load related entities, that is the reason you are facing issue with LoanTypes null in your controller action.to resolve the issue where the LoanTypes property is not being populated when listing loans, you need to ensure that you are eager loading the related LoanTypes entity when querying the Loans entity.
Below is the sample code you could try:
ACBDbContext.cs:
using LoanManagement.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LoanManagement.Data
{
    public class ACBDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ACBDbContext(DbContextOptions<ACBDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Loans> Loans { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LoanTypes> LoanTypes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Loans>().ToTable("loans");
            modelBuilder.Entity<LoanTypes>()
                .ToTable("loanTypes")
                .HasMany(a => a.Loanss)
                .WithOne(b => b.LoanTypes)
                .HasForeignKey(p => p.LoanTypesID);

            // Seed data
            modelBuilder.Entity<LoanTypes>().HasData(
                new LoanTypes { LoanTypesID = 1, Name = "Personal", Profit = "0.05", Type = "fixed" },
                new LoanTypes { LoanTypesID = 2, Name = "Business", Profit = "0.07", Type = "countable" }
            );

            modelBuilder.Entity<Loans>().HasData(
                new Loans { LoansID = 1, FullName = "John Doe", LoanTypesID = 1, LoanAmount = 10000, Capital = 8000, Profit = 500 },
                new Loans { LoansID = 2, FullName = "Jane Smith", LoanTypesID = 2, LoanAmount = 20000, Capital = 15000, Profit = 1400 }
            );
        }


    }
}

LoansController.cs:
using LoanManagement.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace LoanManagement.Controllers
{
    public class LoansController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ACBDbContext _context;

        public LoansController(ACBDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var loans = await _context.Loans
                .Include(l => l.LoanTypes) // Eager loading LoanTypes
                .ToListAsync();
            return View(loans);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(ulong id)
        {
            var loan = await _context.Loans
                .Include(l => l.LoanTypes) // Eager loading LoanTypes
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.LoansID == id);

            if (loan == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            // Calculate Profit based on loan type
            if (loan.LoanTypes.Type == "fixed")
            {
                loan.Profit = Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(loan.LoanTypes.Profit));
            }
            else if (loan.LoanTypes.Type == "countable")
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(loan.LoanTypes.Profit)) > 0 &&
                    Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(loan.LoanTypes.Profit)) < 1)
                {
                    long max = Convert.ToInt64((loan.LoanAmount * Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(loan.LoanTypes.Profit))) / 12);
                    long min = Convert.ToInt64((loan.Capital * Convert.ToInt64(Convert.ToDecimal(loan.LoanTypes.Profit))) / 12);
                    loan.Profit = max + min / 2;
                }
            }

            return View(loan);
        }

    }
}

Loans.cs:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LoanManagement.Models
{
    public class Loans
    {
        [Key]
        public ulong LoansID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("LoanTypesID")]
        public ulong LoanTypesID { get; set; }
        public LoanTypes LoanTypes { get; set; }

        public decimal LoanAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal Capital { get; set; }
        public long Profit { get; set; }

    }
}

LoanTypes.cs:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace LoanManagement.Models
{
    public class LoanTypes
    {
        [Key]
        public ulong LoanTypesID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Profit { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Loans> Loanss { get; set; }

    }
}

Details.cshtml:
 @model LoanManagement.Models.Loans

<h1>Loan Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Loan</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Full Name
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Model.FullName
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Loan Type
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Model.LoanTypes.Name
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Loan Amount
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Model.LoanAmount
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Profit
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Model.Profit
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

Index.cshtml:
@model IEnumerable<LoanManagement.Models.Loans>

<h1>Loans</h1>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Loan Type</th>
            <th>Loan Amount</th>
            <th>Profit</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var loan in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@loan.FullName</td>
                <td>@loan.LoanTypes.Name</td>
                <td>@loan.LoanAmount</td>
                <td>@loan.Profit</td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@loan.LoansID">Details</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

Program.cs:
using LoanManagement.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// Add DbContext
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ACBDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


var app = builder.Build();


using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    try
    {
        var context = services.GetRequiredService<ACBDbContext>();
        DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
    }
}


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();


